# Update Column Value From mysql_fetch_array result PHP

Tags: php

I want to update the value of a column from a mysql table with the result from a mysql_fetch_array

But the last result is just the one being inserted/updated into the column

Where am i having wrong? Here's my code. Thanks in advance

```
    $studentname="some value";
    $course="some value";
    $query=mysql_query("select SABJEK,GRADE,REMARKS from table where STUDENTNAME='$studentname' && STUDENTNUMBER IS NULL") or die(mysql_error());
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
        $sabjek=$result['SABJEK'];
        $grade=$result['GRADE'];
        $remarks=$result['REMARKS'];
        $msg="$sabjek = $grade - $remarks ";
        $msg1="$studentname $course $msg";
        }
    mysql_query("update table2 set `msg`='$msg1' where studentname='$studentname'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: what are you expecting for $msg string?

Comment: @Asik dont know man that's why i ask it here you have idea?

Answer (score 1):

Put the mysql_query inside the while. Basically replace

```
  }
mysql_query("update table2 set `msg`='$msg1' where studentname='$studentname'") or die(mysql_error());
```

with

```
    mysql_query("update table2 set `msg`='$msg1' where studentname='$studentname'") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

and it will work :)

Comment: did not work @motanelu the last result is just the one that was saved any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
  If you want to update the column name every-time whenvere you fetch the result just put update query inside the while loop,   
   $studentname="some value";
   $course="some value";
   $query=mysql_query("select SABJEK,GRADE,REMARKS from table where STUDENTNAME='$studentname' && 
   STUDENTNUMBER IS NULL") or die(mysql_error());
   while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query));
     { $sabjek=$result['SABJEK'];
       $grade=$result['GRADE'];
       $remarks=$result['REMARKS'];
       $msg="$sabjek = $grade - $remarks ";
       $msg1="$studentname $course $msg";        
       mysql_query("update table2 set `msg`='$msg1' where studentname='$studentname'") or         
       die(mysql_error());
     }
```

if you are not expecting this result then please explain me in detail so, i will update the answer.

Thanks.

Comment: there where 2 results from mysql_fetch_array
result 1 and result 2
but result 2 is just the one inserted in the column
why is it? i have placed update inside while thanks

Comment: i want both result 1 and reult 2 to be inserted in the column thanks any idea @a.saleem

Comment: Fine, both results in the same column? if yes,  could you please tell me what is the column data type?

Comment: the column type of msg is text sir

Comment: Fine, 
you want to update the column please put the datatype as varchar,or let it be, consider it as example i am defining result1 is grade and result2 is course 
so , you want to show the values in the same column with separator eg with hyphen (-),
$result1='A'; $result2='Maths'; So, Store it with $result3=$result1.'-'.$resultB; then if you want to show the result separetly just explode with (-) to show them as Grade & Course
Thanks. Please dont call sir :) Cheers!

Comment: While Inserting,  
       $msg="$sabjek = $grade - $remarks ";
       $msg1="$studentname $course $msg";                    
       $msg3=$msg.'-'.$msg1;     
       mysql_query("update table2 set `msg`='$msg3' where studentname='$studentname'") or         
       die(mysql_error());
     }
In detail , to show it in view part, 
eg, 
$result=explode('-',$msg3); $grade=$result[0]; $course=$result[1]; Cheers!.. @kristyan markers

Comment: i've change the datatype to varchar already but did not work as well thanks for helping @a.sallem do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @kristyanmarkes It will work definitely, please tell me the steps what you did, so i can help you here. cause worked almost many times in my project that's why... you can also find my updated comments were have explained for both insert and in view..

Comment: here's what im doing
        $a1=mysql_query("select SABJEK,GRADE,REMARKS from 1st_year_1st_sem where STUDENTNAME='$studentname' && STUDENTNUMBER IS NULL") or die(mysql_error());
  while($b1=mysql_fetch_array($a1))
   {
   $sabjek=$b1['SABJEK'];
   $grade=$b1['GRADE'];
   $remarks=$b1['REMARKS'];
   $msg=$sabjek .'='. $grade .'-'. $remarks;
   $msg1="$studentname $course $present $msg";
   mysql_select_db("ozeki");
   mysql_query("update ozekimessageout set `msg`='$msg1' where studentname='$studentname'") or die(mysql_error());
   }

Comment: while($b1=mysql_fetch_array($a1))
 { $sabjek=$b1['SABJEK']; 
  $grade=$b1['GRADE']; 
  $remarks=$b1['REMARKS']; 
  $msg=$sabjek .'-'. $grade .'-'. $remarks.'-'.$studentname.'-'.$course.'-'.$present.'-';
  mysql_query("update ozekimessageout set msg='$msg' where studentname='$studentname'") or die(mysql_error()); }
we no need two variables were as obviously one is enough. please check with above code.. and just want to ask what was the line mysql_select_db("ozeki");  its the common db right? else are you inserting into another DB? that has table ozekimessageout ?

Comment: did u check whether other database is connecting? is that another server or in the same server? cause 2 database connection something like this?

$dbh1 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); $dbh2 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, true);

mysql_select_db('database1', $dbh1); mysql_select_db('database2', $dbh2); Then to query database 1, do this:

mysql_query('select * from tablename', $dbh1); and for database 2:

mysql_query('select * from tablename', $dbh2);